# Storing relationships in C struct

Tags: c

I want to store relationships of stuff (say persons) in C. I came up with

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  typedef struct rel
  {
    int person;         // person #
    int num;            // number of relationships recorded
    int relationship[]; // the person # of the person's relationships
  } rel;

  rel rels[10];
  int person = 0;
  int num;
  int i;

  // Adding persons
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    rels[i].person = i;
  }

  // Adding random relationships for person #0
  for (i = 1; i < 10; i+=2)
  {
    num = rels[0].num;
    rels[0].relationship[num] = i;
    rels[0].num += 1;
  }

  // Reading all relationships of person #0
  for (i = 0; i < rels[0].num; i ++)
  {
    printf("Person1 (%d) -> Person2: (%d)\n", person, rels[0].relationship[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but I am not sure if it is the correct way to do so. The main purpose is to capture all relationships of a person.

Comment: This approach is wrong because there are no space to store the relationship allocated.

Comment: This is called a "flexible array member". You have to use dynamic allocation for these types of structures, so you can allocate space for the array.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo No, it's a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is wrong because there are no space to store the relationship allocated. You should allocate arrays to store them dynamically.

Also you need to initialize `rels[0].num` before using its value and add one, not two, to `i` to print *all* relationships.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for realloc() */

int main(void)
{
  typedef struct rel
  {
    int person;         // person #
    int num;            // number of relationships recorded
    /* use a pointer for dynamic array */
    int *relationship; // the person # of the person's relationships
  } rel;

  rel rels[10];
  int person = 0;
  int num;
  int i;

  // Adding persons
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    rels[i].person = i;
    /* initialize members */
    rels[i].num = 0;
    rels[i].relationship = NULL;
  }

  // Adding random relationships for person #0
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    /* dynamically re-allocate the array */
    int* newRelationship;
    num = rels[0].num;
    newRelationship = realloc(rels[0].relationship, sizeof(*rels[0].relationship) * (num + 1));
    if (newRelationship == NULL)
    {
      perror("realloc");
      return 1;
    }
    rels[0].relationship = newRelationship;
    rels[0].relationship[num] = i;
    rels[0].num += 1;
  }

  // Reading all relationships of person #0
  for (i = 0; i < rels[0].num; i += 1) /* add one, not two, to print all relationships */
  {
    printf("Person1 (%d) -> Person2: (%d)\n", person, rels[0].relationship[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, if you say so.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I wanted to limit the number of random relationships (rather than all relationships), but replaced `i++` with `i+=2` in the wrong loop.